# 2 You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause SQL2.sql 7 15

Tags: mysql, updates

this is my query:

```
UPDATE pupils p
SET p.rollIdentity = NULL
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT pup469.id FROM pupils pup469
inner JOIN pupils pup470 ON pup470.rollIdentity = pup469.rollIdentity
where pup469.school_id = 469 and pup469.year = 10
AND pup470.school_id = 470 AND pup470.year = 3)
```

so basically, I need to update only the pupils that have the same rollIdentity in the other school. 
I read that I should use exist instead, but I don't fully understand this, can somebody explain further, please? thanks

Comment: testing this:    select p.id from pupils p WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM pupils pup469
  inner JOIN pupils pup470 ON pup470.rollIdentity = pup469.rollIdentity
  where pup469.school_id = 469 and pup469.year = 10
  AND pup470.school_id = 470 AND pup470.year = 3) returns a different number of rows, so it is not the same

Comment: Please provide example data.. i believe your query could be made more simple.

Comment: id  school_id   rollIdentity = {(1,470, 10);(2, 470, null);(3, 469, 10); (4,34,10)}

Comment: in the previous example, (3, 469,10) should be updated to (3, 469, null) only

Comment: Where is the year in your examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bury your sub query a bit deeper

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int,school_id int, rollIdentity int, yr int);
insert into t values
(1,470, 10,3),
(2, 470, null,2),
(3, 469, 10,10),
(4,34,10,4);

UPDATE t p
SET p.rollIdentity = NULL
WHERE p.id IN 
(
select id from
(
SELECT pup469.id
  FROM t pup469
inner JOIN t pup470 ON pup470.rollIdentity = pup469.rollIdentity
where (pup469.school_id = 469 and pup469.yr = 10)
AND   (pup470.school_id = 470 AND pup470.yr = 3)
) s
);

select * from t;
```

You get this

```
+------+-----------+--------------+------+
| id   | school_id | rollIdentity | yr   |
+------+-----------+--------------+------+
|    1 |       470 |           10 |    3 |
|    2 |       470 |         NULL |    2 |
|    3 |       469 |         NULL |   10 |
|    4 |        34 |           10 |    4 |
+------+-----------+--------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But why would you not want id 1 to change?